# Bypass custom authentication method for active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have my application_controller.rb as

```
attr_reader :current_user
private
def authenticate_request
    headers = request.headers
    uid = headers['uid']
    response = User.find_by(:UID => uid)
    @current_user ||= response
    render(json: { message: 'failed', error: "User Could'nt able to authenticate" }, status: :unprocessable_entity) && return unless response
end
```

When I start the rails server and try to open http://localhost:3000/admin/
I get error code as

> {"message":"failed","error":"User Could'nt able to authenticate"}

How to bypass this custom authenticate_request method for active admin.
I can't find any controller related to active admin in the controller's folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have Admin Controller extending application controller, if so then,
On your Admin controller on top, do:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:index]
```

Here i am assuming you want to skip validation for index method, if you want same for other the just add those method like:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]
```

if you would rather skip validation for all method in controller then do only:

```
 skip_before_action :authenticate_request
```

Comment: I am very new to rails. I don't have an admin controller file or rather I can't find that file in controllers.